# SQL query by number of rows in timespan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table in SQL Server called `Cars` that contains a `time` column which is the insertion timestamp of the row:

```
TABLE [Cars] 
(
    [ID] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

I need a query to get all groups of rows that was inserted together more then 3 rows in a 1 minute

the only solution I reached is

```
select a.ID, b.ID, c.ID, a.Time, b.Time, c.Time, c.Time-a.Time as duration
FROM Cars a
INNER JOIN Cars b on b.Time-a.Time < '1900-01-01 00:01'
INNER JOIN Cars c on c.Time-a.Time < '1900-01-01 00:01'
WHERE b.time > a.time and c.time > a.time
```

But its seems to be too heavy if I try it for more then 3 rows in a minute.

Any other suggestion will be welcome

Comment: Please don't re-post your same question over and over again ...

Comment: @marc_s This is not an exact duplicate. Poster had added his code as requested in the other question - unfortunately he made it a new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following

```
SELECT
    COUNT(C.[ID]),
    c.[Time]
FROM
    [Cars] AS C
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, C.[Time]),
    DATEPART(MONTH, C.[Time]),
    DATEPART(DAY, C.[Time]),
    DATEPART(HOUR, C.[Time]),
    DATEPART(MINUTE, C.[Time])
HAVING
    COUNT(C.[ID]) > 3
```